# Specific man page for shell built-in commands like 'source'

Tags: shell, command-line, manpage

If you execute any of the following in the command line

```
man source 
man readonly
man suspend
...
```

The output is the same manpage describing shell built-in commands in general.

I've searched for 'source' on line and I've found this more specific documentation:

> Linux / Unix Command: source
>
> Command Library
> NAME
>
> source - Evaluate a file or resource as a Tcl script
> SYNOPSIS
>
> source fileName
> source -rsrc resourceName ?fileName?
>
> source -rsrcid resourceId ?fileName?

How can I output something similar in my terminal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try doing this in a shell :

```
help source
```